# Creating a Macro that Creates a new row at a changing point

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro in excel to add a new row at the end of a specific data point and then move the format from the row above to the new row.

Basically:
In the format below: how would I create a row below Task 2 without breaking the formatting from Project Name 2? Also, with the addition of more rows a specific cell will not work.

Project Name 1:

Task 1:

Task 2:

Project Name 2:

Task 1:

Thanks

Comment: So where is your current code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for....

If "Task 2" is in Column A then it looks for it and had a row under it if "Task 2" is found.
Hope I helped.

```
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
tk2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
If sht.Cells(tk2, "A").Value = "Task 2" Then
    sht.Cells(tk2, "A").Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
End If
```